# JQGrid dirty check

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid with checkbox column and two buttons (Save & Cancel) in a form. Initially Save button is disabled. I want to enable the Save button when use check the checkbox column in the JQGrid and disable Save button when user uncheck (dirty check).. I tried using JQuery plugin AreYouSure for dirty check but it's not working for JQGrid.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

jqGrid has a dirty cell function. Not sure if it will get triggered onChange of a checkbox

```
var dirtyRows = $('#gridContainer').jqGrid('getChangedCells', 'dirty');
```

See here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing